# HTTP / HTTPS GET Request Alexa Skill - "The Response is Invalid" Lambda Response

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am building an Alexa skill that tells a user the closest Kaiser Permanente hospital, clinic, or pharmacy. When I test using one of the three keywords, I get the error: `The response is invalid.`

Giving an invalid (using none of the three keywords) response gives me the error: `The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid.`

I am at a loss as to how to figure out what or where the issue is, as I am not given any details about the issue.

```html
function getWelcomeResponse(callback) {
  var speechOutput = "Welcome to the Kaiser Permanente Alexa Skill. Allow me to help you find the nearest Kaiser hospital, pharmacy, or clinic.";
  var reprompt = "Would you like me to help you find the nearest Kaiser hospital, pharmacy, or clinic?";
  var header = "Kaiser Permanente Skill";
  var shouldEndSession = false;
  var sessionAttributes = {
    "speechOutput" : speechOutput,
    "repromptText" : reprompt,
  };

  callback(sessionAttributes, buildSpeechletResponse(header, speechOutput, reprompt, shouldEndSession));
}

function handleGetKaiserBuildingIntent(intent, session, callback) {
  var buildingType = intent.slots.Building.value.toLowerCase();
  var speechOutput = "We have an error fam.";

  if (buildingType != BLDG_TYPE.PHARMACY ||
      buildingType != BLDG_TYPE.CLINIC ||
      buildingType != BLDG_TYPE.HOSPITAL) {
    speechOutput = "Please try again. I can help you find the nearest Kaiser hospital, clinic, or pharmacy.";
    var repromptText = "Please try again. I can help you find the nearest Kaiser hospital, clinic, or pharmacy.";
    var header = "Error fam.";
  } else {
    getJSON(function(data) {
      if (data != "ERROR") {
        speechOutput = data;
      }
      callback(session.attributes, buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard(speechOutput, "", true));
    }, buildingType);
  }
}

function getJSON(callback, building) {
  request.get(url(building), function(error, response, body) {
    var d = JSON.parse(body);
    var result = d.list[0].contents.title;

    if (result != null) {
      callback(result);
    } else {
      callback("ERROR");
    }
  });
}

function url(building) {
  switch (building) {
    case BLDG_TYPE.HOSPITAL:
      return "http://xjzxdss0040x.dta.kp.org/search/cgi-bin/query-meta?v%3Aproject=kp-mg-facdir-project&v:sources=kp-mg-facdir-proximity&query=hospital&user_lat=37.928243&user_lon=-121.9700594&render.function=json-feed-display-brief&content-type=application-json";
      break;
    case BLDG_TYPE.PHARMACY:
      return "http://xjzxdss0040x.dta.kp.org/search/cgi-bin/query-meta?v%3Aproject=kp-mg-facdir-project&v:sources=kp-mg-facdir-proximity&query=pharmacy&user_lat=37.928243&user_lon=-121.9700594&render.function=json-feed-display-brief&content-type=application-json";
      break;
    case BLDG_TYPE.CLINIC:
      return "http://xjzxdss0040x.dta.kp.org/search/cgi-bin/query-meta?v%3Aproject=kp-mg-facdir-project&v:sources=kp-mg-facdir-proximity&query=clinic&user_lat=37.928243&user_lon=-121.9700594&render.function=json-feed-display-brief&content-type=application-json";
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can check the cloudwatch logs to get more details on what went wrong in the lambda execution.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say what your problems is with what you've given. It could be an improperly uploaded Lambda function or your JSON response could be too big and thus hitting the response size limit. The best start to trouble shooting this problem is to look at your error logs in Cloudwatch and see what that says.

Comment: Hi, Ann, what's Cloudwatch and how can I use it to help me debug? I wish I could provide more information, but this was all the information I was given via the Service Simulator from the Amazon Dev Console. I wish they would provide more information than just a vague error response. Is there anything else I could provide that may help?

Comment: The JSON response is quite large, however, I do not know what the limit is. In addition, in my `getJSON()` function, I am only grabbing a string, `title,` as shown on the line `var result = d.list[0].contents.title;`

Comment: cloudwatch is an aws specific monitoring dashboard: aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch‎. Once you log in and go to "logs" in the left nav, you should see logs for your skill. Usually there's more info here about why you're erroring out. And in terms of response size (and this is your skill response not like a JSON response from an API call), limit is 24576 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try returning a simple, hardcoded string when the GET request returns to make sure everything up to that point is working correctly. Then replace the hardcoded string with data from the response.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'll try that. Other theories I have is that it is an internal website that Alexa is trying to access from the outside or that the JSON returning object is too large.